# ViewBinding - Does exposing views through get() cause a performance issue?

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently I migrated my project to ViewBinding and as a way to make it less verbose, I decided to expose it through get() property and it seems to be working fine, but some other developers are saying that it may cause memory issues because it's assigning a value to a variable, which I think it's not doing this, since it's exposing through the *get() property*. Example:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val textView: TextView get() = binding.textViewID

    private val binding by lazy { MyActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
}
```

can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a property with a getter and no initial assignment, there is no backing field generated. So no, this is not wasting memory.

The way you wrote it on one line looks very similar to code where there is no getter defined and you are assigning an initial value to a backing field. Maybe your colleagues misread your code. I usually define getters on the next line so it looks distinct. Otherwise, it is easy to accidentally omit `get()` when you intended to include it.

Even if it were creating a backing property, surely you don't have enough views referenced that it would even approach an amount of memory use that you should waste your time worrying about it.

Comment: If you need proof for your colleagues, you can open the Kotlin bytecode viewer (View -> Tool Windows -> Kotlin bytecode), and then click Decompile, and it will show what the Java code approximately would look like.